# Function to print a new line after printing the alphabet 10x, each time on a new line while only using putchar() only twice

Tags: c

It should be noted that I'm not allowed to use the standard library for this. I have a header file called "main.h" which contains the function prototype for a function that does what the conventional "putchar()" function does (mine is called _putchar(), I know, creative).

The issue now is that what I've written doesn't print a new line at the end of my program without me having to breach the limit of using "_putchar()" not more than twice.

This is what I have so far:

```
void print_alphabet_x10(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char c;
        for (c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
            _putchar(c);
        }
        if (i != 9)
            _putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the conditional on the printing of `'\n'`, you will have a new line after each alphabet, even after the 10th.

```c
void print_alphabet_x10(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char c;
        for (c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
            _putchar(c);
        }
        _putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the loop by 1 and place a condition before the `_putchar`.

For instance an `if`statement like:

```
void print_alphabet_x10(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char c;
        for (c = 'a'; c <= 'z' + 1; c++) {
            char tmp;
            if (c <= 'z') {
                tmp = c;
            } else {
                tmp = '\n';
            }
            _putchar(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Or more compact by using the ternary conditional, i.e. `?:`, like:

```
void print_alphabet_x10(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char c;
        for (c = 'a'; c <= 'z' + 1; c++) {
            _putchar(c <= 'z' ? c : '\n');
        }
    }
}
```